# how to filter table data according to Auth::user->id(); in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using this Controller to get permission to users to there projects

```
public function show($id)
 {
     if (Permission::where('status', 1)->where('project_id', $id)->exists()) {
    // if((Permission::where('status', '=', '1')->first()) && (Permission::where('project_id','=',$id)->first())){
        $project = Project::find($id);
        $tasks = $this->getTasks($id);
        $files = $this->getFiles($id);
        $comments = $this->getComments($id);
        $collaborators = $this->getCollaborators($id);
        $permissions = $this->getPermissions($id);
returnview('collaborators.show')->withProject($project)->withTasks($tasks)->withFiles($files)->withComments($comments)->withCollaborators($collaborators);
        }
    else if
        //return('hi');
        (Permission::where('status', 2)->where('project_id', $id)->exists()) {
            $project = Project::find($id);
            $tasks = $this->getTasks($id);
            $files = $this->getFiles($id);
            $comments = $this->getComments($id);
            $collaborators = $this->getCollaborators($id);
            $permissions = $this->getPermissions($id);
             return view('collaborators.manager')->withProject($project)->withTasks($tasks)->withFiles($files)->withComments($comments)->withCollaborators($collaborators);
        }
```

My permission model is

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permission extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'permissions';


    protected $fillable = ['status','project_id','collaborator_id'];

    public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }

    public function scopeProjectp($query, $cid)
    {
        return $query->where('collaborator_id', $cid);
    }




    public function scopePermissioneditt($query, $id, $projectId)
    {
        return $query->where('collaborator_id',$id)->where('project_id',$projectId);//->exists();

    }


    public function scopeProjectac($query)
{
     return $query->where('collaborator_id', Auth::user()->id);

}




  /*  public static function permission($collaboratorId, $projectId)
{
    return Permission::where('collaborator_id', $collaboratorId)->where('project_id', $projectId);
}*/

     public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'collaborator_id');
    }

  /*   public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
    }*/


      public function project_collaborator()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Collaboration','collaborator_id');
    }




    //
}
```

I need check and access permission table according to current user Auth::user->id; to give permission users.

Comment: I am not sure what you are wanting to do, here. Can you elaborate a bit on what should do what? It's hard to follow as is.

Comment: OK, My current system cannot identify logged user to give permission. because according to my codes in permission table if there are two values (status) 1 and 2 with same project_id (like 10). system unable to understand users permission values. it is automaticaly move to highest values permission. that means if there are two users with diffrent permission values 1 and 2 for same project. and when both of  user acess the system always identify values 2 as permission value.

Comment: It's moving to 2 when you pass it the user's id using Auth::id()? You should be able to query this. For example: `$perms = Permission::where("user_id", Auth::id())->where("project_id", $projectId)->first()` would theoretically get this (just assuming your table setup because I do not know your table architecture.

Comment: I wil try it thanks

Comment: If that doesn't work just let me know. Then I may need you to provide your database architecture.

Comment: ok I will try and inform you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129572/discussion-between-scott-plunkett-and-fernando).

Comment: OK,Scott I think according to My table structure there is column as collaborator_id it is same to logged user id. so, if we can compare collaborator_id with logged user_id. then problem will solve. so, how can compaire this line with collaborator_id and Auth user Id **(Permission::where('status', 1)->where('project_id', $id)->exists())**